# Google App Engine Error: <gcloud.app.deploy> INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded:BACKEND_SERVICES (quota: 5, used: 5 + needed 1)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my node application on Google App Engine Flexible Environment. Previously it was working well but yesterday it starts refusing giving this error:

> Error:  INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were
>   exceeded:BACKEND_SERVICES (quota: 5, used: 5 + needed 1)

How can I sort that problem? I am still using the free trial credit that google gives.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By default, the quota on number of GAE Flex versions you have is 5. A few options to be able to deploy once you hit this limit:

- **Stop GAE Flex versions**: if you have running versions that you don't need, you can stop them to free up the backend services being used by them. That can be accomplished by using gcloud or using Cloud Console (go to App Engine => Versions):
  https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions
- **Delete Backend Services**: if you're using backend services directly and don't need them, you could delete them. That can also be done via gcloud or Cloud Console (go to Networking => Load Balancing):
  https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/loadbalancing/advanced/backendServices/list
- **Quota Increase**: Alternatively, you can request a backend service quota increase:
  https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746?hl=en

Comment: In terms of **Quota Increase** , you may be able to increase Quota by yourself. 

From GCP console, go to IAM & admin, select Quotas and then you can edit quotas.

Comment: @ntakashi And just to note on that… editing quotas using console still requires approval from GCP.

Comment: @KyleMorgan, thanks! It's right. I had to put the reason to increase Quota and phone number when I did it. After 15 minutes Google approved it.

Comment: What is a backend service?

Comment: I can't delete the backend services; they keep auto-starting..