# How to fix google-cloud app-engine flexible-environment quota issue

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, terminal, cloud, quota

I have a deployed app engine service with a flexible environment which I'm trying to update, by running from the terminal:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I am met with this error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The following quotas were exceeded: BACKEND_SERVICES (quota: 5, used: 5 + needed: 1), IN_USE_ADDRESSES (quota: 8, used: 8 + needed: 1).
```

I have only one other service running with a flexible environment.

In the past, I fixed this problem by stopping, then deleting older versions of my service (or of the other one running on the flexible environment). 
This problem was caused now because I deleted a version without stopping it first. I have a feeling these versions still occupy my "quota", though I can't see them anywhere (not in the web GUI, nor in the terminal).
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43656886) wherein there are options that can be followed to stop the error.

It is possible that the backend load balancer or the VM instances of your App Engine Flex still exist even if you have removed the whole service. You can verify it through the following:

- *Load Balancer* (Cloud Console -> Network Services -> Load balancing -> Backends) https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/backends/list
- *VM Instances* (Cloud Console -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances)
  https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

If there is no existing backend, you can file a [support ticket](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) to verify if:

- Your project quotas are still maxed out.
- The service backends are still active only that they do not reflect in Cloud Console.

Comment: Thanks. There are no backends listed there, and yet I'm still getting the quota issue. It seems I have to upgrade my account to get a support ticket, but I don't see any other option right now. Is this a bug that a service still takes a quota even after it's deleted?

Comment: This can be filed as a bug especially if you are still encountering the error but nothing is visible in your Console. If you cannot upgrade your account, you can open a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187250&template=1162927) and they will try to check your project if there are ghost resources.